# In igx-grid, is it possible to prevent a row from being selected when a cell is selected?

Tags: angular, selection, igx-grid

My problem seems simple, I use row selection to bring up an edit form for a record.  I have one column with hyperlinks to a new tab and a bunch of other columns.  That works fine, but I want my users to be able to cut/copy and paste from the other cells as well, but once you click in a cell, the cell selection functions runs and then the row selection runs.  I was able to program around the row selection occurring on the hyperlink column using the field name.  The simplest solution to me would be to only bring up the edit form when selecting a row by the left-hand checkboxes and not when clicking in a cell, but let the cell be selected for something like copy/paste.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the cell selection only for the Edit form? The [eventArgs](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/interfaces/IGridCellEventArgs.html) will give you the cell, from where you [can access the row](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/interfaces/CellType.html) and fill in your Edit form (I guess this is the approavh that you take). This approach wont bring the row selection visuals.

Another approach would be to set a **custom grid theme** for the row styling and set colors that will cover your scenario:

[image]

Documentation [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/sass/latest/index.html#mixin-theme)

And [working live-sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nangc?file=src/app/grid/grid-multi-cell-selection-style/grid-multi-cell-selection-style.component.scss) to play around with